# Which should I use: "in" or "at"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to write an essay about Prufrock.

Which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

> it takes place in big, foggy city **at** a soft October night.
>   it takes place in big, foggy city **in** a soft October night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one is correct. The correct sentence is:

> "**It** takes place in **a** big, foggy city **on** a soft October night."

Answer (score 2):

Ditto Bill Franke.

There's an odd pattern to the prepositions used with "when phrases". Normally, we say something happened "at" a time, "on" a day, and "in" a longer period of time.

> It takes place **at** five o'clock.
>
> It takes place **at** sundown.
>
> It takes place **on** Thursday.
>
> It takes place **on** the first day of August.
>
> It takes place **in** October.
>
> It takes place **in** 1992.

Prepositions for parts of the day get tricky. We generally say "in the morning" or "in the evening". Perhaps that makes sense if you think of "the morning" as a long period of time and an event takes just a moment "in" that time.

But we say "at night", which isn't really consistent. Sometimes people say "in the night", but that's rare and comes across as slightly poetic. On the other hand we routinely say "in the nighttime" and "in the daytime". Unless it's a specific night, in which case it becomes "on", like "on the night of October 1". That seems consistent to me because now we're talking about a date, so we use "on".